# Except block not catching exception in ipython notebook

Tags: python, exception, environment

When I try this simple example in my current Python environment (a ipython notebook cell) I am not able to catch TypeError exception:

```
a = (2,3)
try:
  a[0] = 0
except TypeError:
  print "catched expected error"
except Exception as ex:
  print type(ex), ex
```

I get:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

When I try to run the same copy-pasted code in a different ipython notebook on the same computer  I get the expected output: `catched expected error`.

I understand it has something to do with my current environment, but I have no idea where to start looking! I tried also another example with AttributeError and in that case the catch block works.

**EDIT:**
When I tried:

```
   >>> print AttributeError
   <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>
   >>> print TypeError
   <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>
```

I remembered that earlier in the session I made an error, which renamed TypeError:

```
try:
    group.apply(np.round, axis=1) #group is a pandas group
except  AttributeError, TypeError : 
#it should have been except  (AttributeError, TypeError)
    print ex
```

which gave me:

```
 ('rint', u'occurred at index 54812')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be that the TypeError has to be implicitly imported for some environments:

```
from exceptions import TypeError
```

Give that a go!

Comment: Thanks, it works! This reminded me to try to test the actual class of what I call TypeError (see edit) . Then I followed your suggestion and everything works as expected

Comment: This re-binds the `TypeError` name as a global; better to not do `TypeError = AttributeError` in the first place, or clean up with `del TypeError` so the built-in name is no longer masked.

Answer (score 1):

This line is at fault here:

```
except  AttributeError, TypeError :
```

This means: catch exceptions of type `AttributeError`, and assign that exception to the name `TypeError`. In essence, you did this:

```
except AttributeError as e:
    TypeError = e  # instance of AttributeError!
```

You can rectify this with

```
del TypeError
```

so that Python finds the built-in type again.

The better solution is to use the correct syntax:

```
except (AttributeError, TypeError):
```

Because of how easy it is for that mistake to be made, Python 2.6 [added the `except .. as` syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes), and the older syntax using `except Exception, name:` has been removed from Python 3 altogether.